# jQuery: Load Div content into another div?

Tags: jquery

I have multiple hidden divs on the page each holding different content, when I click a link on the page e.g.

```
<a href="#contentone" class="clicky">Load content one</a>
<a href="#contenttwo" class="clicky">Load content two</a>

<div id="contentone">Some content here to be loaded into another div</div>
<div id="contenttwo">Some content here to be loaded into another div</div>

<div id="slider">
  This content to be replaced by content from links/hidden divs
</div>
```

Currently I'v got this setup so it loads the content from an external source, but i'd prefer it to populate the slider with content hidden on the page (As above).

My current jquery is below, would love this this to be converted to work within hidden divs on the page opposed to external files.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(function () {
    $(".clicky").click(function () {
                var url = this.href;
                var e = $("#slider");
                e.load(url, function() {
                    e.animate({width: "show"}, 500);
                });
                return false;
    });
});
});//]]>  

</script>
```

Comment: Can't you simply set the html of your $("#slider") to be the html of your hidden div ?
$("#slider").html($('hidde_div').html());

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use `.load`.

```
$(function () {
    $(".clicky").click(function () {
        var content_id = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#slider').hide().html($(content_id).html()).show(500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

***[THE WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ARN2a/)***.

Comment: That's broken the slider, e.g. it won't slide out now :(

Comment: You star! That will do nicely, thank you very much for your time today :)